# Survey App is missing in SharePoin Online even after activating Team Collaboration Lists feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey-list

I am trying to create a survey in SharePoint Online. When I clicked on add an app "Survey App" is missing.

I activated the Site Feature "Team Collaboration Lists". Bit still "Survey App" is missing.

Is there any other settings/dependent Feature that I need to activate.

[image]

Thank You,
Rohit Waghela

Answer (score 0):

what's the current site template that you are using?

Try to deactivate and activate the “Team Collaboration Lists” feature and check again.

Clear the browser cache or use other browser to check if the issue exists.

Or try to use PnP PowerShell to enable the SurveyLists feature:

```
#Config Variable
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Sites/sitename"
$FeatureId = "00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102" #Web Scoped SurveyLists Feature

#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#get the Feature
$Feature = Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web -Identity $FeatureId

#Get the Feature status
If($Feature.DefinitionId -eq $null)
{    
    #Activate the Feature
    Write-host -f Yellow "Activating Feature..."
    Enable-PnPFeature -Scope Web -Identity $FeatureId -Force

    Write-host -f Green "Feature Activated Successfully!"
}
Else
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Feature is already active!"
}
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Activate Feature using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/sharepoint-online-activate-feature-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Survey App only shows in menu in "classic" mode, is totally missing in Modern UI.